# pycharm refactoring yields wrong imports

Tags: python, pycharm

I am working on a project with a nested project structure shown below.

When I perform any refactoring that involves a change to an import statement, PyCharm generates the import without the top level directory. For example, if a new file needs access to src->domain->money->Currency, it generates:

`from domain.money import Currency`

but what is needed to run is
`from src.domain.money import Currency`

If I type out "src" manually it runs correctly, but who wants to do that?
What is the fix?

Cheers

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, your src directory is marked as [content root](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-project-structure.html#remove). This way, pycharm will always make imports relative to that root.
To "fix" this (it's a feature, because the published part of your package sits in the src directory), you could remove the content root.

The easiest way to do this, is to right-click the blue src folder and choose "Mark directory as" (bottom-most entry) and "Unmark as sources root".

[image]

But again, it's a feature, and I would carefully think about why you need to import straight from the bottom of your project instead of from your src root.

Comment: That worked, but even after I read the link, I still don't understand why it's a good thing. Or how I would have to restructure the project to use it. IF you can add any insight I'd appreciate it. Cheers

Comment: To be clear, now that I unmarked the folder I get an import statement that does start at 'src', the top. When I had it marked, it incorrectly started at 'domain' (one level down).

Comment: I am no expert with this, maybe [this article](https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2014/05/25/python-packaging/#the-structure) might help on why there is a src directory in the first place. When publishing the project, everything below the src directory gets dropped and hence all the imports will not be functional anymore. If you are not in a situation where anything will be published as a package, you can use both (with or w/o sources root), but if you decide to package this, the import will fail.